# Django send_mail() is not grouping emails together based on subject in outlook and apple mail

Tags: python, django, outlook, gmail, apple-mail

I am using Django's send_mail() for my email notifications, and I need to send multiple follow up mails which needs to be grouped together based on the same subject. Gmail groups the emails automatically based on the same subject line, but for some reason Outlook and Apple Mail doesn't group them. This results in email spamming in the inbox.I even tried to change the outlook settings to thread conversations, but still no luck.Is there anything I am missing out here ?

Answer (score 0):

For outlook you need to add some extra headers, e.g. topic-header.
Take a look at [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=411601), it might be helpful